# want to purge queue in remote machine rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I am having rabbitmq up and running in another machine with ip address 10.8.11.12 on port 15672 and in that i am having a queue named "hello". I want to purge hello queue from my machine using CLI (command line interface)

I have tried following to purge queue in localhost

rabbitmqctl purge_queue

it is working fine

and i am trying the same like this

rabbitmqctl purge_queue -p 10.8.11.12 hello

here i am considering 10.8.11.12 as vhost. is it correct?

what actually vhost means in rabbitmq?

Even a simple link will help.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `-n` parameter as:

`rabbitmqctl  -n rabbit@your_other_machine purge_queue hello`

here is an example:

`./rabbitmqctl  -n rabbit@srv-rabbit-cent01 purge_queue my_queue_1`

where `rabbit@srv-rabbit-cent01` is the rabbitmq node name. ( `srv-rabbit-cent01` is the hostname )

about the vhost please read here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html

> 2.4. Vhost
>
> The vhost component is used as the basis for the virtual-host field of
>   the connection.open AMQP 0-9-1 method. Any percent-encoded octets in
>   the vhost should be decoded before the it is passed to the server.

Comment: your_other_machine means ip address like 10.8.11.12 or systemname.companyname.com (full computer name displayed in system properties) ?

Comment: The rabbitmq node name so the `hostname`